# Extjs: two panel resize accordingly when window resizes

Tags: extjs, resize, panel, scale

I have a panel containing two children panels.the parent panel uses "border" layout, while two children panels use "form" and "column" layouts respectively. now How can I make these two children panels resize accordingly when window resizes, i.e., make sure the size ratio of these two panels is constant.

thanks!

my codes are as follows:

```
itemRts = {
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Route',
    region: 'north',
    autoHeight: true,
    layout: 'form',
    width: 294,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:10px 12px 10px',
    id: 'ROUTE_PANEL',
    el: 'Route_Setup',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Go',
        anchor: '0',
        id: 'GO_BTN'

    }]
};

itemEvts = {
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Events',
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'column',
    tpl: 'Please put events here.',
    //bodyStyle: 'padding:10px 12px 10px',
    border: false,
    hideBorders: true,
    id: 'EVENT_PANEL',
    el: 'Event_Legend',
    autoScroll: true
};

newView = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: "border",
    items: [

    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        margins: '10 0 10 10',
        region: 'center',
        width: 200,
        layout: 'border',
        split: true,
        boxMaxWidth: 280,
        minWidth: 280,
        id: 'RTS_EVTS_REGION',
        collapseMode: 'mini',
        items: [
        itemRts,
        itemEvts]
    }]
});
```

how to modify above codes to make it work as what I want?

thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your main container, i suggest hbox and/or vbox layouts. those layouts are what you are looking for. here a sample:

```
var testPanel = new Ext.Viewport( {
    id : 'vp_test',
    layout : 'hbox',
    align : 'stretch',
    items : [
        {
            id : 'pnl_child_1',
            title : 'Test 1',
            flex : 2
        },
        {
            id : 'pnl_child_2',
            title : 'Test 2',
            flex : 3,
            layout : 'vbox',
            align : 'stretch',
            items : [
                {
                    id : 'pnl_child_3',
                    title : 'Test 3',
                    flex : 1
                },
                {
                    id : 'pnl_child_4',
                    title : 'Test 4',
                    flex : 1
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
} );
```

you can refer to documentation, [viewport](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.layout.HBoxLayout?class=Ext.Viewport), [hbox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.layout.HBoxLayout), [vbox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.layout.VBoxLayout)

```
   itemRts = {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Route',
        // region: 'north', <<< we don't need this anymore
        flex: 1, // this means that this container has 1 flexible share
        // autoHeight: true, <<< this will ruin all layout
        layout: 'form',
        // width: 294, <<< we don't need this anymore
        bodyStyle: 'padding:10px 12px 10px',
        id: 'ROUTE_PANEL',
        el:'Route_Setup',
        items: [
            {
                xtype:'button',
                text:'Go',
                anchor:'0',
                id:'GO_BTN'
            }
        ]
    };
    itemEvts = {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Events',
        // region: 'center', <<< we don't need this anymore
        flex: 1, // this means that this container has 1 flexible share
        layout: 'column',
        tpl: 'Please put events here.', // <<<< if you're not going to use xTemplates you should use html property instead
        //bodyStyle: 'padding:10px 12px 10px',
        border: false,
        hideBorders: true,
        id: 'EVENT_PANEL',
        el : 'Event_Legend',
        autoScroll: true
    };

newView = new Ext.Viewport({
//// if you have only one child component you can use fit layout for viewport. 
//// and consider removing that only child. use viewport as main container.
    layout : "border", 
    items: [ 
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            margins: '10 0 10 10',
            region: 'center',
            // width: 200, <<<< width has no effect on center region
      /// we'll use hbox with align stretch
            layout: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch',
            // split: true, <<<< split has no effect on center region
            // boxMaxWidth: 280, <<<< no effect
            // minWidth: 280, <<<< no effect
            id: 'RTS_EVTS_REGION',
            // collapseMode: 'mini', <<<< collapse properties has no effect on center region
            items: [
                itemRts,
                itemEvts
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: hi i attach my codes in my question. i tried modifying it based on your suggestion, but still cant get to the point. would you kindly give me more hints? thanks!

Comment: first of all autoHeight is not what you want. it resizes the container by calculation its childrens and it will not let you specify any height. and border layout isn't fluid at all. using horizontalBox and verticalBox layouts will provide you best fluid layouts. i'm going to change my sample with your code.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a resize event for container panel and call "dolayout" method of their children in case of resize :

```
newView = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: "border",
    items: [

    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        margins: '10 0 10 10',
        region: 'center',
        width: 200,
        layout: 'border',
        split: true,
        boxMaxWidth: 280,
        minWidth: 280,
        id: 'RTS_EVTS_REGION',
        collapseMode: 'mini',
        items: [itemRts, itemEvts],
        listeners: {
            'resize': function () {
                itemRts.doLayout();
                itemEvts.doLayout();
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Exactly how I would have done it, calling doLayout on panel should refresh them.

Comment: why browser says "itemRts.doLayout is not a function"?

Comment: Try with "itemRts.doLayout()". If itemRts is a panel it must work.